# Django debug toolbar loads but doesn't show on the local server even after proper installation

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

I have installed django debug toolbar correctly on a pipenv environment and done the main steps, such as adding internal_ips of 127.0.0.1 and adding the debug toolbar to installed_apps and middleware but still whenever I run the server and open a template of an app the debug toolbar doesn't show.
However if I open the page source in the browser, it shows all the list elements of the toolbar however the toolbar doesn't display, does anyone know what is going wrong and how I could fix it.

This are the changes made to the settings.py file:

```
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)
mimetypes.add_type("text/css", ".css", True)
mimetypes.add_type("text/html", ".html", True)
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'playground',
    'debug_toolbar',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

INTERNAL_IPS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
]
```

And the following changes to the urls.py folder:

```
import debug_toolbar

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls))
]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You use browser from localhost or you use some kind of development server?. maby add yours ip address

Comment: I am using the browser from localhost, do I still need to add my personal ip address?

Answer (score 0):

Use that `debug_toolbar.apps.DebugToolbarConfig` in `INSTALLED_APPS` instead of `debug-toolbar`. Like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     ...
   'debug_toolbar.apps.DebugToolbarConfig',  ...
]
```